# Browser sends GET instead of POST

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, http

I have a javascript function sending post requests the way plain html form does it. Here is the function implementation:

```
function sendDirectPost(uri, data) {
    var $form = $('<form action="' + withContext(uri) + '" method="POST"></form>');
    appendDataToForm($form, data);
    $form.submit();
}

function appendDataToForm($form, data) {
    var body = $('body');
    _.each(data, function (value, key) {
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden">')
            .attr('name', key)
            .attr('value', value));
    });
    $form.css('display', 'none');
    $form.appendTo(body);
    return $form;
}
```

The purpose is to simulate plain form post submit with javascript, so I don't have to apply redirects with javascript explicitly.

In the majority of browsers this function does what I expect. However in some cases it doesn't. For some reason it sends GET request. I haven't managed to reproduce it however logging service shows from user agent that the browsers are Safari 8.0 or Android Web Kit Browser. Maybe there are some others but I didn't check all.

Here are the questions:
1. What might be the problem with the approach?
2. Are there other ways to implement standard form submit behavior with javascript? Maybe using $.ajax() function?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, using `$.ajax()` or even [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) would be much better and safe. Iw you want to POST data with js there no reason to do it with HTML form.

Comment: The problem with $.ajax() or $.post() is that I always have to process response and directly add redirect logic. When I use form submit I don't have to add redirect on the client side.

Comment: one line of code for a redirect with js is less than overhead with HTML